# prestashopwebservice API posting a new customer to the database by using a form

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, api, prestashop-1.7

First of all i don't know if the title is the best but i've tried to describe it as best as possible.

So i'm currently working on a project that makes use of the PrestashopWebserviceLibrary, I'ts simply sad, working with a prestashop API. and i've encounterd a problem that i can't solve.

So the objective is to post a new customer to the database through a form. The form has a submit button that works with angular so `ng-click="function()"`. The funtion then gathers all the variables from the form, puts it into an `$.ajax POST` request and sends it to the file `set.php`. In this file we'll make the request to the database to insert everything. The file makes use of `XML`.

I think this will make it more understandable:

**The form**

```html
<form ng-controller="CustomerController" class="bottomborderinput margin-t-25 col-md-11 col-lg-10 col-xl-8">
<div class="form-group justify-content-between">
  <label class="padding-r-30 custom-radio">{{ 'Aanhef' | translate }}</label>
   
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
   <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
   <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
   <span class="custom-control-description">{{ 'Dhr.' | translate }}</span>
  </label>
  
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
   <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
   <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
   <span class="custom-control-description">{{ 'Mevr.' | translate }}</span>
  </label> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Voornaam' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Achternaam' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-12">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Straat en huisnummer' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residential" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Postcode' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="area_code" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Plaats' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="form-group row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Land' | translate }}</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="country">
    <option value="Netherlands">Nederland</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Telefoon nr.' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Bedrijfsnaam' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="company_name" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'BTW nummer' | translate }}</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-12">
   <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Klantgroep' | translate }}</label>
   <select name="customer_group" class="form-control">
    <option value="Default">{{ 'Standaard' | translate }}</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group text-center margin-b-10">
  <button ng-click="RegisterCustomer()" type="submit" name="register_customer" class="defaultbutton mediumbutton">
   <svg class="align-middle float-left " width="27" height="25" viewBox="13 12 27 21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M23.065 32.28c-.287 0-.575-.124-.8-.373l-8.182-9.057c-.47-.52-.494-1.394-.052-1.95.443-.554 1.183-.58 1.653-.06l7.365 8.153 14.395-16.6c.46-.532 1.2-.523 1.652.022.452.544.443 1.416-.018 1.95L23.882 31.886c-.227.262-.522.393-.817.393z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
   </svg>{{ 'Klant toevoegen' | translate }}
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**The function in app.js**

```js
myApp.controller('CustomerController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('config/customers.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response.data.customers.customer
    });
    $scope.RegisterCustomer = function() {
        var pre = $('radio').val();
        var firstname = $('firstname').val();
        var lastname = $('lastname').val();
  var residential = $('residential').val();
  var area_code = $('area_code').val();
  var city = $('city').val();
  var country = $('country').val();
  var phone = $('phone').val();
  var company_name = $('company_name').val();
  var customer_group = $('customer_group').val();


        $scope.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{pre:pre, firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname, residential:residential, area_code:area_code, city:city, country:country, phone:phone, company_name:company_name, customer_group:customer_group},
            url:"config/set.php" // PHP Page URL To php code saving the input to the database
            })
};
});
```

**set.php**

```html
<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<?php
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'Example.nl/prestademo');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'example123');
require_once "PSWebServiceLibrary.php";


    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

    // Here we make the WebService Call
    $psXML = <<<XML
    <prestashop>
    <customer>
      <id/>
      <id_shop_group>2</id_shop_group>
      <id_shop>1</id_shop>
      <id_gender>1</id_gender>
      <id_default_group>3</id_default_group>
      <id_lang>1</id_lang>
      <id_risk>0</id_risk>
      <company>123</company>
      <siret/>
      <ape/>
      <firstname><![CDATA[. $firstname .]]></firstname>
      <lastname>Test</lastname>
      <email>Test2@email.com</email>
      <passwd>asd</passwd>
      <lastpasswd_gen/>
      <birthday/>
      <newsletter>0</newsletter>
      <ip_registration_newsletter/>
      <newsletter_date_add/>
      <optin>0</optin>
      <website>easywebs.nl</website>
      <outstanding_allow_amount/>
      <show_public_prices>0</show_public_prices>
      <max_payment_days>0</max_payment_days>
      <secure_key/>
      <note/>
      <active>1</active>
      <is_guest>0</is_guest>
      <deleted>0</deleted>
      <date_add/>
      <date_upd/>
      <reset_password_token/>
      <reset_password_validity/>
    </customer>
    </prestashop>
XML;
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($psXML);
    $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);
?>
```

**The debugging response.**

```html
RETURN HTTP BODY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
 <id><![CDATA[34]]></id>
 <id_default_group xlink:href="https://example.nl/prestademo/api/groups/3"><![CDATA[3]]></id_default_group>
 <id_lang xlink:href="https://example.nl/prestademo/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_lang>
 <newsletter_date_add></newsletter_date_add>
 <ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
 <last_passwd_gen><![CDATA[2017-10-12 04:40:08]]></last_passwd_gen>
 <secure_key><![CDATA[c1d6050c9869552de049868e8029374a]]></secure_key>
 <deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
 <passwd><![CDATA[$2y$10$CyIJLPNvX1.yx7xRiyWMtegtSneyf8nNPXs3WklFdPq6BT0EzlgTi]]></passwd>
 <lastname><![CDATA[Test]]></lastname>
 <firstname><![CDATA[.  .]]></firstname>
 <email><![CDATA[Test2@email.com]]></email>
 <id_gender><![CDATA[1]]></id_gender>
 <birthday></birthday>
 <newsletter><![CDATA[0]]></newsletter>
 <optin><![CDATA[0]]></optin>
 <website><![CDATA[easywebs.nl]]></website>
 <company><![CDATA[123]]></company>
 <siret></siret>
 <ape></ape>
 <outstanding_allow_amount></outstanding_allow_amount>
 <show_public_prices><![CDATA[0]]></show_public_prices>
 <id_risk><![CDATA[0]]></id_risk>
 <max_payment_days><![CDATA[0]]></max_payment_days>
 <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
 <note></note>
 <is_guest><![CDATA[0]]></is_guest>
 <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
 <id_shop_group><![CDATA[2]]></id_shop_group>
 <date_add><![CDATA[2017-10-12 10:40:08]]></date_add>
 <date_upd><![CDATA[2017-10-12 10:40:08]]></date_upd>
 <reset_password_token></reset_password_token>
 <reset_password_validity></reset_password_validity>
<associations>
<groups nodeType="group" api="groups">
 <group xlink:href="https://sdwebdesign.nl/prestademo/api/groups/3">
 <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
 </group>
</groups>
</associations>
</customer>
</prestashop>
```

As you can see i'm trying to pass the variable `$firstname` as the posted item through the `XML` but sadly the return is empty. So yes the post does work, the items do get inserted into the database, except for my post variables.

**PS: the `$scope.ajax` in the `app.js` file is a test. I've also tried just `$.ajax` and both seem to work fine.**

**Progress edit**

Changing the variable `$firstname = $_POST['firstname']` to $firstname = 'test'; Does work. also i've tried using the `<firstname>{$firstname}</firstname>` in the XML document which also works fine. So the error is somewhere in the POST request.

The error is an 500 error with the response:

```
&lt;message&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Validation error: &quot;Property Customer-&gt;firstname is empty.&quot;]]&gt;&lt;/message&gt;
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem.

As told in the **progress edit** section it had something to do with the post.

The issue was that:

```
var firstname = $('firstname').val();
```

An empty value had. So changing the `.val();` to:

```
$('input[name="setFirstname"]').val();
```

Solved the problem. 
Bit of a stupid problem actually since i could've seen it by myself.
But for anyone who's having the same issue i'm leaving this answer.

Create the form and set the:

```
<input type="text" name="setFirstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" value="">
```

Input name:

```
<input name="Javascript .val">
```

So you're able to grab the input value by using:

```
var firstname = $('input[name="setFirstname"]').val();
```

Then the `$.ajax` request and `set.php` do get the values passed.

Cheers!